# Proper drag and drop of scaled image in RaphaelJS

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, transformation

I've managed to implement dnd of image in RaphaelJS by changing its **x** and **y** attributes in *move* method. I click on the image and I can move it around and everything works as expected.

**Effect I now want to achieve**:

- User clicks on the image and it is scaled by a factor of 1.2 user
- Moves the image around when the mouse button is released the image
- Scales down to the original size
- *Everything should look smooth and natural

**What I'm doing**:

- When user clicks the image: memorizing x,y of the image, `image.scale(1.2)`
- While moving: `image.attr({x: (dx/1.2)+startx});` `image.attr({y: (dy/1.2)+starty});`
- On mouse relase: `image.scale(1.0)`

**Current Effect**: works fine until I release the mouse button -> the image scales down to original size ***but it also*** jumps a bit right or left depending on starting position

Is there an easy way to deal with my problem in RaphaelJS or do I have to dive into complicated transformations?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you memorize the x,y of the image before scaling, which is then probably not exactly correct

You could also try to set center of the shape manually
http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.scale

Comment: Might be that the problem is with initial startX and startY. Now i guess the position after START_MOVE is calculated correctly with scale in mind. But the position of the image after move is finished is still calculated for the scaled image. When I have more time to check this out I will report back in this question. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

I found that using transform worked good for me.  You use it like this el.transform('s1.5,s1.5');